# Request previous results in a RSS channel

Tags: rss, request, feed

I am developing an application that reads a RSS channel from a website. The problem is that this RSS offers results of football matches on the last weekend, but I am also interested on previous weekends.

Is it possible to request RSS information of previous dates, not only the last one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if the web site does not offer it. An RSS feed is from the clients perspective just a simple XML file, and it is quite likely that what you get from the web site is the only thing they are publishing at the moment.

Your options are to:

- Check if the site publishes the data via some other feed, or if they offer some other way of getting older data.
- Implement your own memory of results.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going with second option. The site does not offer older data, and if they do it's like a summary of previous post, not the whole information I need. Thanks!!